# Java - Getting the answer to a calculation using variables

Tags: java, variables, calculator

How can I return the answer to a calculation where the two numbers and operator used are stored in variables (*input from the user*).

I am creating a simple calculator and trying to output the answer to ***"Number" "Operator" "Number2"*** which can be anything depending on what the user inputs.

```
int Number;
int Number2;
int Operator;
String OperatorString;

do 
{
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    Number = UserInputScanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("1. + \n");
    System.out.println("2. - \n");
    System.out.println("3. * \n");
    System.out.println("4. / \n");

    Operator = UserInputScanner.nextInt(); 

       switch (Operator) {
        case 1:  OperatorString = "+";          
                 break;
        case 2:  OperatorString = "-";
                 break;
        case 3:  OperatorString = "*";
                 break;
        case 4:  OperatorString = "/";
                 break;
        default: OperatorString = "Invalid Operator";
                 break;
    }
    System.out.println(OperatorString);

    System.out.println("Enter another number");
    Number2 = UserInputScanner.nextInt();       

    Answer = "Number" + "OperatorString" + "Number2";
    System.out.println(Number + OperatorString + Number2 + "=" + Answer);
```

The output from this when inputting these numbers and operator returns "5+5=5+5" and I am trying to return "5+5=10".

Comment: you are simply concatinating string in answer `Answer = "Number" + "OperatorString" + "Number2";` this will not give you desired answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java provides no built-in way of evaluating a `String` expression with operators to produce a value of the result, so you would need another switch to compute `Answer`:

```
switch (Operator) {
    case 1:  Answer = Number + Number2;
             break;
    case 2:  Answer = Number - Number2;
             break;
    case 3:  Answer = Number * Number2;
             break;
    case 4:  Answer = Number / Number2;
             break;
    default: Answer = 0;
             break;
}
```

The structure of the switch is identical to the one that you have before reading the second number, so you can combine the two if you move the reading of `Number2` before the switch.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the answer in Switch block itself

```
int Number;
int Number2;
int Operator;
String OperatorString;

do 
{
System.out.println("Enter a number");
Number = UserInputScanner.nextInt();

System.out.println("1. + \n");
System.out.println("2. - \n");
System.out.println("3. * \n");
System.out.println("4. / \n");

Operator = UserInputScanner.nextInt(); 
System.out.println("Enter another number");
Number2 = UserInputScanner.nextInt(); 
   switch (Operator) {
    case 1:  OperatorString = "+"; 
             Answer = Number + Number2;
             break;
    case 2:  OperatorString = "-";
             Answer = Number - Number2;
             break;
    case 3:  OperatorString = "*";
             Answer = Number * Number2;
             break;
    case 4:  OperatorString = "/";
             Answer = Number / Number2;
             break;
    default: OperatorString = "Invalid Operator";
             break;
}
System.out.println(OperatorString);




System.out.println(Number + OperatorString + Number2 + "=" + Answer);
```